# PDF Looses Saturation when Exported at a Lower Resolution

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, resolution, saturation, vibrance

I exported my PDF with images from Illustrator, but the file was too large (around 35 MB), so I exported it with the PDF/X-1a:2001 setting to lower the resolution. The file was smaller as I wanted, but I noticed that that the color in the images had lost a lot of vibrance and saturation and the images were just a lot duller. I would really like to know if there a way to prevent this from happening while also keeping the files at a relatively small size (like <5 MB)? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

PDF/X uses CMYK color, If your artwork is RGB, that's why there's a change. Distilling to PDF/X will auto-convert colors to CMYK in the PDF/X options.

Answer (score 0):

Define your exporting parameters from start.

1. Export directly to another PDF format that supports the RGB files directly.
2. Configure the exporting options. JPG compression and resampling.
3. Include the color profile.